# How can I print non static method address?

Tags: c++, pointers, static

I want to print address of method f1.

I don't want to make it static.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class a1{
public:
    void f1(){   
    }
};
int main(){
    a1 ma;
    cout << &ma.f1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? There's no portable way to do that specifically.

Comment: @George in SetWindowsHookEx i should register a call back method and i don't want to register an static one because i have to change all methods and properties as static to use them in my callback function.